# Can someone help me figure out this sound?

Tags: sound-effects, noise, sound-effects-recording, sound-fx, horse

It is NOT a horse, donkey, elk, creaky door, yak call, pig, moose, a rubber chicken, antique car horn, coyote, rooster, or a elephant. Please help I have been struggling for a week!

Answer (score 1):

Best guess: A pig. 
Alternative: A door opening and floorboards creaking when the person starts walking through the door.